# Get the index of a value in a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing

I have something in `bash` like

```
myArray=('red' 'orange' 'green')
```

And I would like to do something like

```
echo ${myArray['green']}
```

Which in this case would output `2`. Is this achievable?

Comment: My first suggestion is to use python instead of bash for scripting. Once I started doing that, I never looked back.

Comment: Thank you, I know I could do it easily with a python dictionary, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_array=(red orange green)
value='green'

for i in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
   if [[ "${my_array[$i]}" = "${value}" ]]; then
       echo "${i}";
   fi
done
```

Obviously, if you turn this into a function (e.g. get_index() ) - you can make it generic

Comment: This is not going to work with sparse arrays or associative arrays. To have it work with all types of arrays, replace your C-style for loop with this: `for i in "${!my_array[@]}"; do`. Also, you may want to `break` the loop if index is found if you only want to find the first index.

Comment: Can you please explain what `!` means in `${!my_array[@]}`?

Comment: @bodacydo, I wondered `!` means too, then tried it and saw that instead of listing all the values in the array, it lists indexes starting from zero.

Comment: The `!` means to return index of the element instead of the value of the element.

Comment: Why the semicolon after echo? Isn't that unnecessary?

Comment: yes, a semicolon after a statement is unnecessary in bash. For most statements, a newline indicates the end of the statement. You can choose however you will for code clarity and readability

Answer (score 38):

You must declare your array before use with

```
declare -A myArray
myArray=([red]=1 [orange]=2 [green]=3)
echo ${myArray['orange']}
```

Comment: This is some way of creating an associated array. Nice.

Comment: not working in GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I cannot comment on 4.1.2 (4.1 is from 2009), but on my current Bash (Ubuntu 16.04, Bash 4.3.42) it still works as advertised.

Comment: OP wanted an index not a value.

Comment: @Dejan Yes, that's in the title. But also look at the question to see, what OP want's to achieve.

Answer (score 23):

There is also one tricky way:

```
echo ${myArray[@]/green//} | cut -d/ -f1 | wc -w | tr -d ' '
```

And you get 2
[Here are references](https://superuser.com/a/778840/342613)

Comment: Ingenious solution. Only reason I don’t mark this simpler one as accepted (although I upvote it) is it is a bit more error prone. While the [currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15028821/1661012) will `echo` nothing when inputing an invalid colour, this solution will input the number of elements in the array plus one (so `3`, following my example array), which might be a bit harder to debug.

Answer (score 15):

No. You can only index a simple array with an integer in `bash`. Associative arrays (introduced in `bash` 4) can be indexed by strings. They don't, however, provided for the type of reverse lookup you are asking for, without a specially constructed associative array.

```
$ declare -A myArray
$ myArray=([red]=0 [orange]=1 [green]=2)
$ echo ${myArray[green]}
2
```

Comment: that always print 2 despite the argument... also red and orange prints 2. GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Associative arrays need to be explicitly declared; whether I knew that in 2013 or simply forgot to do so in this answer is up for debate :)

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to be correct.  Answers which suggest iterating over the array (or letting some command line tool do it for you) are missing the point.  To get O(1) reverse lookups it appears that you need to declare two associative arrays:  One for key->value and one for value->key.  All insertions should then be conducted through a wrapper function which adds them to both arrays.

Answer (score 10):

A little more concise and works in Bash 3.x:

```
my_array=(red orange green)
value='green'

for i in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
   [[ "${my_array[$i]}" = "${value}" ]] && break
done

echo $i
```

Comment: This appears to be @SteveWalsh's answer from 5 years earlier (now 10 years ago), but broken in that it will claim the value is the last element in the array when it is NOT in the array.  This answer should be deleted or edited to replace `&& break` with `echo $i && break`

Answer (score 6):

Another tricky one-liner:

```
index=$((-1 + 10#0$(IFS=$'\n' echo "${my_array[*]}" | grep --line-number --fixed-strings -- "$value" | cut -f1 -d:)))
```

features:

- supports elements with spaces
- returns `-1` when not found

caveats:

- requires `value` to be non-empty
- difficult to read

---

Explanations by breaking it down in execution order:

```
IFS=$'\n' echo "${my_array[*]}"
```

set array expansion separator (`IFS`) to a new line char & expand the array

```
grep --line-number --fixed-strings -- "$value"
```

grep for a match:

- show line numbers (`--line-number` or `-n`)
- use a fixed string (`--fixed-strings` or `-F`; disables regex)
- allow for elements starting with a `-` (`--`)

  cut -f1 -d:

extract only the line number (format is `<line_num>:<matched line>`)

```
$((-1 + 10#0$(...)))
```

subtract 1 since line numbers are 1-indexed and arrays are 0-indexed

- if `$(...)` does not match:

  - nothing is returned & the default of `0` is used (`10#0`)
- if `$(...)` matches:

  - a line number exists & is prefixed with `10#0`; i.e. `10#02`, `10#09`, `10#014`, etc
  - the `10#` prefix forces base-10/decimal numbers instead of octal

---

---

Using `awk` instead of `grep`, `cut` & bash arithmetic:

```
IFS=$'\n'; awk "\$0 == \"${value//\"/\\\"}\" {print NR-1}" <<< "${my_array[*]}"
```

features:

- supports elements with spaces
- supports empty elements
- less commands opened in a subshell

caveats:

- returns  when not found

---

Explanations by breaking it down in execution order:

```
IFS=$'\n' [...] <<< "${my_array[*]}"
```

set array expansion separator (`IFS`) to a new line char & expand the array

```
awk "\$0 == \"${value//\"/\\\"}\" {print NR-1}"
```

match the entire line & print the 0-indexed line number

- `${value//\"/\\\"}` replaces double quotes in `$value` with escaped versions
- since we need variable substitution, this segment has more escaping than wanted

Comment: I like the awk solution, the other has too much bash black magic for my taste :P...  believe it's more portable and encouraged to use `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | [...]` rather than `IFS=$'\n' [...] <<< "${arr[*]}"`, I. Additionally, it is worth noting that the awk solution will print *every* matching index. To only return the first/leftmost index, you can call the awk function `exit` in the block after printing (i.e. `awk "... {print NR-1; exit}"`. To return the last rightmost index, store NR-1 in a var and print at END: `awk "... {result = NR-1} END {print result}"`.

Answer (score 3):

This might just work for arrays,

```
my_array=(red orange green)
echo "$(printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}")" | grep -n '^orange$' | sed 's/:orange//'
```

Output:

```
2
```

If you want to find header index in a tsv file,

```
head -n 1 tsv_filename | sed 's/\t/\n/g' | grep -n '^header_name$' | sed 's/:header_name//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

I like that solution:

```
let "n=(`echo ${myArray[@]} | tr -s " " "\n" | grep -n "green" | cut -d":" -f 1`)-1"
```

The variable n will contain the result!

Answer (score 2):

This is just another way to initialize an associative array as chepner showed.
Don't forget that you need to explicitly `declare` or typset an associative array with `-A` attribute.

```
i=0; declare -A myArray=( [red]=$((i++)) [orange]=$((i++)) [green]=$((i++)) )
echo ${myArray[green]}
2
```

This removes the need to hard code values and makes it unlikely you will end up with duplicates.

If you have lots of values to add it may help to put them on separate lines.

```
i=0; declare -A myArray; 
myArray+=( [red]=$((i++)) )
myArray+=( [orange]=$((i++)) )
myArray+=( [green]=$((i++)) )
echo ${myArray[green]}
2
```

Say you want an array of numbers and lowercase letters (eg: for a menu selection) you can also do something like this.

```
declare -a mKeys_1=( {{0..9},{a..z}} );
i=0; declare -A mKeys_1_Lookup; eval mKeys_1_Lookup[{{0..9},{a..z}}]="$((i++))";
```

If you then run

```
echo "${mKeys_1[15]}"
f
echo "${mKeys_1_Lookup[f]}"
15
```

Answer (score 2):

In zsh you can do

```
xs=( foo bar qux )
echo ${xs[(ie)bar]}
```

see zshparam(1) subsection Subscript Flags

Answer (score 2):

This outputs the 0-based array index of the query (here "orange").

```sh
echo $(( $(printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}" | sed -n '/^orange$/{=;q}') - 1 ))
```

If the query does not occur in the array then the above outputs `-1`.

If the query occurs multiple times in the array then the above outputs the index of the query's first occurrence.

Since this solution invokes sed, I doubt that it can compete with some of the pure bash solutions in this thread in efficiency.

Comment: You don't need `tr`. Just do `printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}"`. It seems you're not really comfortable with Bash, so that's why you find your solution easier. You should learn Bash idioms, and then you'll never write these horrors again `:)`.

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf, that is definitely an improvement. I've updated, using `printf` instead of `tr`. Hopefully only half as horrific now. :)

Comment: It looks a bit weird, but it's not that bad in fact: it actually works with elements containing spaces (but still not as robust as some other answers).

Comment: I agree this is readable as is, but being 1-based indexed while bash arrays are 0-based may cause confusion on a larger script.

Comment: @user137369 I agree. I have now revised my solution to output the 0-based index. This results naturally in an output of `-1` when the query does not occur in the array.

Comment: I liked this one but had problems on mac (sed complained) and needed a way to accept variables that could contain any non-newline character. I replaced the `sed` with `grep -nxFm 1 '$ITEM' | cut -f1 -d:`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to repeatedly look up values in the array, you could build a reverse index out of an associative array.

```
my_array=(red orange green)
declare -A my_ass_arr

for i in ${!my_array[@]}; do my_ass_arr[${my_array[$i]}]=$i; done

this_val="green"
echo ${my_ass_arr[$this_val]}
```

This way you only loop through the array once. I'm not sure what bash does under the hood with associative arrays as far as indexing and searching, but it might be faster than a brute force search every time.

Answer (score 1):

This one outputs the 1based NEUROMANCER index of the character "Molly" ;)

```
get_index() {

  declare -n dummy_array="$1"
  # alternative: split read -ra array <<< "${dummy_array[@]}"
  local array=( "${dummy_array[@]}" )
  # alternative: local value; value="$( for dummy_value; do true; done; echo "$dummy_value" )"
  local value=$2
  local length="${#array[@]}"
  local i=0
  
  while (( i < length ))
  do
    if [ "${array[$i]}" = "$value" ]
    then echo $(( i + 1 )); return 0
    fi; (( i++ ))
  done
  
  echo "$2 not found beneath $1"
  exit 1

}

NEUROMANCER=(Case Molly Riviera)
get_index NEUROMANCER Molly
get_index NEUROMANCER 'John Doe'
```

If you then run:

```
$ bash script.sh
2
John Doe not found beneath NEUROMANCER
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows some methods for returning an index of an array member.
The array uses non-applicable values for the first and last index,
to provide an index starting at 1, and to provide limits.

The while loop is an interesting method for iteration, with cutoff,
with the purpose of generating an index for an array value,
the body of the loop contains only a colon for null operation.
The important part is the iteration of i until a match,
or past the possible matches.

The function indexof() will translate a text value to an index.
If a value is unmatched the function returns an error code that can be
used in a test to perform error handling.
An input value unmatched to the array will exceed the range limits `(-gt, -lt)` tests.

There is a test (main code) that loops good/bad values, the first 3 lines are commented out, but try some variations to see interesting results (`lines 1,3 or 2,3 or 4`). I included some code that considers error conditions, because it can be useful.

The last line of code invokes function indexof with a known good value "green" which will echo the index value.

```
indexof(){
  local s i;

  #   0    1   2     3    4
  s=( @@@ red green blue @o@ )

  while [ ${s[i++]} != $1 ] && [ $i -lt ${#s[@]} ]; do :; done

  [ $i -gt 1 ] && [ $i -lt ${#s[@]} ] || return

  let i--

  echo $i
};# end function indexof

# --- main code ---
echo -e \\033c
echo 'Testing good and bad variables:'
for x in @@@ red pot green blue frog bob @o@;
do
  #v=$(indexof $x) || break
  #v=$(indexof $x) || continue
  #echo $v
  v=$(indexof $x) && echo -e "$x:\t ok" || echo -e "$x:\t unmatched"
done 

echo -e '\nShow the index of array member green:'
indexof green
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray=('red' 'orange' 'green')
echo ${myArray[@]}
arrayElementToBeRemoved='orange'
echo "removing element: $arrayElementToBeRemoved"
# Find index of the array element (to be kept or preserved)
let "index=(`echo ${myArray[@]} | tr -s " " "\n" | grep -n "$arrayElementToBeRemoved" | cut -d":" -f 1`)-1"
unset "myArray[$index]"
echo ${myArray[@]}
```

Comment: `tr` will fail for array elements with spaces in them. Use `printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}"` instead. You should also use `egrep` and `^pattern$` or it will match substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar myself and avoiding a loop, came up with ...

```
myArray=('red' 'orange' 'green')
declare -p myArray | sed -n "s,.*\[\([^]]*\)\]=\"green\".*,\1,p"
```

... which leaves stdout unsullied should the element not be found...

```
$ myArray=('red' 'orange' 'green')
$ declare -p myArray | sed -n "s,.*\[\([^]]*\)\]=\"green\".*,\1,p"
2

$ declare -p myArray | sed -n "s,.*\[\([^]]*\)\]=\"gren\".*,\1,p"
$
```

After which I googled, found this question and thought I'd share ;)

Comment: Ingenious solution, but it’s hard to read and becomes problematic if one of the options contains double quotes. Furthermore, text parsing in this manner is finicky and I wouldn’t trust it to work indefinitely (thought it probably will). Finally, `typeset` is marked as obsolete even by the ancient Bash in macOS; `declare` should be used instead.

Comment: TFT @user137369 - the double quotes observation is a good spot - TBH, I never even considered it coz they weren't suggested and I didn't need to consider them for my own use :) I did know about declare(1), but obvs didn't realise that typeset(1)'s been "demised".

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to the answer of @pointo1d but easier to read:

```
# myArray=('red' 'orange' 'green')
# declare -p myArray | grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=]="green")'
2
```

`(?=string)` is called a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which allows matching something (in our case a number) followed by something else which won't be added to the result.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
function array_indexof() {
  [ $# -lt 2 ] && return 1
  local a=("$@")
  local v="${a[-1]}"
  unset a[-1]
  local i
  for i in ${!a[@]}; do
    if [ "${a[$i]}" = "$v" ]; then
      echo $i
      return 0 # stop after first match
    fi
  done
  return 1
}

a=(a b c d)
i=$(array_indexof "${a[@]}" d)
echo $i # 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Purest bash function:

```sh
_indexof() {
        for ((;$#;)) ; do
                case "$1" in
                        --) shift ; break ;;
                        -*) printf "Usage: %s [--] VALUE ARRAY...\n" "$FUNCNAME" >&2 ; return 2 ;;
                        *) break ;;
                esac
                shift
        done
        local asize value=$1
        shift
        asize=$#
        ((asize)) || { printf "Usage: %s [--] VALUE ARRAY...\n" "$FUNCNAME" >&2 ; return 2 ;}
        while (($#)) ; do
                [[ "$1" != "${value}" ]] || break
                shift
        done
        (($#)) || return 1
        echo $((asize-$#))
}
```

- ✓ work with any inputs
- ✓ work even with "set -e"
- ✓ integrate helping error message
- ✓ return non-zero on error (1 if not found, 2 if non-proper call)
- ✓ output first index if found

Example:

```sh
set "Peace & Love" "ПТН Х̆ЛО" "Cupidity" "Vanity" "$(printf "Ideology\nFear")" "Bayraktar"
_indexof "Vanity" "$@"
```

Return 0, output "3".

Answer (score -1):

It works for me in zsh

```
declare -a myArray=('red' 'orange' 'green')

value='green'

echo ${myArray[(I)$value]}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution:

```
my_array=(red orange green)
# ^ and $ delimits the beginning and end of the exact match.
echo ${my_array[*]} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '/^green$/ {print NR-1}'
```

Comment: This also fired on words that *contain* `green`, which is not the intended result (exact matches).