# How to detect array start index by current shells (zsh/bash)?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, indexing, zsh

We all know arrays in Bash are indexed from zero, and in zsh are indexed from one.

How can the script know it should use 0 or 1 if I can't ensure the running environment is bash, zsh or something else?

Expected code sample:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

detect_array_start_index(){
  # ... how?
  echo 1
}
ARR=(ele1 ele2)
startIndex=$(detect_array_start_index) # 0 or 1
for (( i=${startIndex}; i < ${#ARR[@]} + $startIndex; i++ )); do
    echo "$i is ${ARR[$i]}"
done
```

I have a idea is find the index of the first value in a fixed array, I got this: [Get the index of a value in a Bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028567/get-the-index-of-a-value-in-a-bash-array), but the accepted answer use bash variable indirection syntax `${!VAR[@]}`, which is invalid in zsh.

Comment: Don't expect the same script to run under `bash` and `zsh` in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the index 1 element of a two element array:

```
detect_array_start_index() {
  local x=(1 0)                                                   
  echo ${x[1]}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `KSH_ARRAYS` option in `zsh` to force array indexing to start at 0.

```
{ setopt KSH_ARRAYS || : ; } 2> /dev/null

ARR=(ele1 ele2)
for ((i=0; i < ${#ARR[@]}; i++ )); do
  echo "$i is ${ARR[$i]}"
done
```

The command group and redirection allows the entire command to act as a no-op if executed from `bash`. The preceding code produces the same output in `zsh` and `bash`.